# logback not writing to log files

Tags: java, spring, gradle, logging, logback

I have a logback xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false" scan="true">
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="LOGFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>/mnt/test/testLog.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>/mnt/test/testLog_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <minIndex>1</minIndex>
                <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>

            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    <logger name="weblogic" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE"/>
    </logger>
        <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
        <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
        <logger name="org.test.abc" level="INFO" />
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </root>

</configuration>
```

My gradle entry is as follows:

build.gradle dependencies is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:8.0.1'
    // junit
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // logger
    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:0.9.26'
    // jackson
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:2.13.3'
    // hibernate
    implementation 'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final'
    // apache
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.16'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.16'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.16'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1'
    //  lombok
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    // swagger
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-integration:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    // guava
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    // jjwt
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    // spring
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.2.7.RELEASE'
    // Spring security
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.5.0.RELEASE'
    // AWS S3 related Jars
    implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 's3', version: '2.17.282'

    deploy files(war)
}
```

While I compile and deploy the loggers appears in the console output but nothing is written to the  /mnt/test/testLog.log file. The reason i have given the dependecies is to make sure there is no version mismatch. Can someone let me know where am i going wrong with the gradle implementation.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have not actually used the file appender with a real logger section - there may not be any loggers with exact name as 'weblogic' in your runtime

```
<logger name="weblogic" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE"/>
</logger>
```

to test if it works try

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE"/>
</root>
```